# Making an image slide with a timer?

Tags: javascript, css

How would I go about making a set of images slide after a video has been either exited out of or is no longer running?

Here is the site in question: http://www.mcbridesrv.voicemktg.com/

When you visit it, you get a video that pops up.

How can I get the image slides to slide every 7 seconds after you get out of the video popup?

Currently just using CSS - Would I have to use JS or could I use CSS animation to make it slide every few seconds? Even if the video is playing - as a last resort I guess.

Might be a really dumb question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag. Since you didn't include relevant code, I can only give you pseudo.

```
// Global
var videoClosed = false;

// in whatever makes the slideshow run
if(videoClosed){
    // run slideshow
}

// In whatever closes the video
setTimeout(function(){ videoClosed = true; }, 7000);
```